# String de conexión a una base de datos MySQL usando INNODb desde c# (Visual Studio)

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2017, innodb

mi pregunta es muy sencilla: Cómo puedo conectarme a mi base de datos de MySQL (con INNODb) desde C#?

Es para un proyecto que estoy desarrollando, y tengo el problema de que no encuentro en ningún sitio cuál es la String de conexión que tengo que usar.
Probé varias, y ninguna funcionó. Obviamente, ya sabía que no iban a funcionar, ya que eran de OleDB, Access...pero oye, uno nunca pierde la esperanza.

Cualquier respuesta será súper agradecida porque es lo último que me falta para acabar este proyecto.

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Hola Denis, revisá [éste](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43438/Connect-C-to-MySQL) enlace, tal vez te sirva para guiarte un poco. Saludos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te dejo un ejemplo simple por acá.

**C# DataAdapter method**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

// addded these
using MySql.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Data;

namespace mysql
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string DB_CONN_STR = "Server=127.0.0.1;Uid=foo_dbo;Pwd=pass;Database=foo_db;";

            MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection(DB_CONN_STR);

            try {

                string sqlCmd = "select * from users order by user_id";

                MySqlDataAdapter adr = new MySqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd, cn);
                adr.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                adr.Fill(dt); //opens and closes the DB connection automatically !! (fetches from pool)

                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows){
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("user_id = {0}", dr["user_id"].ToString()));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{oops - {0}", ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                cn.Dispose(); // return connection to pool
            }
            Console.WriteLine("press any key...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

**C# DataReader ejemplo:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

// addded these
using MySql.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Data;

namespace mysql
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string DB_CONN_STR = "Server=127.0.0.1;Uid=foo_dbo;Pwd=pass;Database=foo_db;";

            MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection(DB_CONN_STR);

            try {

                string sqlCmd = "select * from users order by user_id";

                cn.Open(); // have to explicitly open connection (fetches from pool)

                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sqlCmd, cn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (rdr.Read()){
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("user_id = {0}", rdr["user_id"].ToString()));   
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{oops - {0}", ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                cn.Dispose(); // return connection to the pool
            }
            Console.WriteLine("press any key...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias por contestar! Pues ahora gracias a todos vuestros comentarios pude progresar, pero ahora me da otro error, y es un InvalidOperationException.

Comment: En el futuro se recomienda que hagas una breve explicación de como funciona tu respuesta, ya que la idea del sitio es aprender. Muchas gracias por colaborar.

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero es definir el connection string

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;
```

[MySQL connection strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/)

Es muy simple porque lo que importa es la libreria de ado.net para mysql que utilizas.

Para eso usa nuget y referencia la libreria

[MySql.Data nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data/)

y por ultimo el codigo que podria ser algo como esto

```
using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("<connection string>")) {   
    conn.Open();   

    string query = "INSERT INTO NombreTabla (campo1, campo2) VALUES (?param1, ?param2)";   
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);   

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?param1", TextBox1.Text);   
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?param2", Convert.ToInt32(TextBox2.Text));   

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();   

}
```

Comment: Soy relativamente nuevo en lo de databases (del todo, vaya) así que puede que sea algo frustrante, pero yéndonos a nivel muy básico, como le indico yo el lugar (ruta) en la que se encuentra mi database?

Comment: no hay ruta, se instala el motor de base de datos como servicio, o sea no es Ms Access, sino mas bien como Sql Server